# Typescript: Deep Assertions with AWS-CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to assert that API-Gateway is linked to the correct handler:

Below is the SYNTH output: where I can see API-Gateway is linked to my read lambda function:

```
    "GatewayproxyANYApiPermissionMyTestStackGatewayDAACF61FANYproxyCE4F4129": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ReadLambda25A29444",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
...
```

Here is the test code:

```
test('API Gateway Created', () => {
  const app = new cdk.App();
  // WHEN
  const stack = new CdkCloudFormationAppreciationDashboard.CdkCloudFormationAppreciationDashboardStack(app, 'MyTestStack');
  // THEN
  expectCDK(stack).to(haveResource("AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"));
  expectCDK(stack).to(haveResource("AWS::Lambda::Permission", {
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  }));
});
```

Unable to get detail link testing between the gateway and lambda.

Full Synth:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "Messages804FA4EB": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "messsage",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "messsage",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
          "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
        }
      },
      "UpdateReplacePolicy": "Delete",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete"
    },
    "ReadLambdaServiceRole786C9B4A": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "arn:",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                },
                ":iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "ReadLambdaServiceRoleDefaultPolicy6518FF35": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "dynamodb:*",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": [
                {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "Messages804FA4EB",
                    "Arn"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "PolicyName": "ReadLambdaServiceRoleDefaultPolicy6518FF35",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "ReadLambdaServiceRole786C9B4A"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "ReadLambda25A29444": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Ref": "AssetParameters9f901872866f870648f5c33e2a134e29d428ef5dae05062b86e526b1012df22fS3Bucket503CC46A"
          },
          "S3Key": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                {
                  "Fn::Select": [
                    0,
                    {
                      "Fn::Split": [
                        "||",
                        {
                          "Ref": "AssetParameters9f901872866f870648f5c33e2a134e29d428ef5dae05062b86e526b1012df22fS3VersionKey6307BBBE"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Fn::Select": [
                    1,
                    {
                      "Fn::Split": [
                        "||",
                        {
                          "Ref": "AssetParameters9f901872866f870648f5c33e2a134e29d428ef5dae05062b86e526b1012df22fS3VersionKey6307BBBE"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ReadLambdaServiceRole786C9B4A",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            "TABLE": {
              "Ref": "Messages804FA4EB"
            }
          }
        },
        "Handler": "index.lambda_handler",
        "Runtime": "python3.8"
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "ReadLambdaServiceRoleDefaultPolicy6518FF35",
        "ReadLambdaServiceRole786C9B4A"
      ]
    },
    "Gateway43CB3636": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": "Endpoint for a simple Lambda-powered web service",
        "Name": "Gateway"
      }
    },
    "GatewayCloudWatchRole34305E06": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "arn:",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                },
                ":iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "GatewayAccount6D7AA49C": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Account",
      "Properties": {
        "CloudWatchRoleArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "GatewayCloudWatchRole34305E06",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "Gateway43CB3636"
      ]
    },
    "GatewayDeployment880EB8C2e63c4fa30ea1ca6a01c3a1154d803307": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
      "Properties": {
        "RestApiId": {
          "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
        },
        "Description": "Automatically created by the RestApi construct"
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "GatewayproxyANYCE067C19",
        "Gatewayproxy441946D2",
        "GatewayANY8DB43F89"
      ]
    },
    "GatewayDeploymentStageprod62BC6904": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
      "Properties": {
        "RestApiId": {
          "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
        },
        "DeploymentId": {
          "Ref": "GatewayDeployment880EB8C2e63c4fa30ea1ca6a01c3a1154d803307"
        },
        "StageName": "prod"
      }
    },
    "Gatewayproxy441946D2": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
      "Properties": {
        "ParentId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "Gateway43CB3636",
            "RootResourceId"
          ]
        },
        "PathPart": "{proxy+}",
        "RestApiId": {
          "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
        }
      }
    },
    "GatewayproxyANYApiPermissionMyTestStackGatewayDAACF61FANYproxyCE4F4129": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ReadLambda25A29444",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
        "SourceArn": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "arn:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
              },
              ":execute-api:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              },
              ":",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
              },
              ":",
              {
                "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
              },
              "/",
              {
                "Ref": "GatewayDeploymentStageprod62BC6904"
              },
              "/*/*"
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "GatewayproxyANYApiPermissionTestMyTestStackGatewayDAACF61FANYproxy666D8DEA": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ReadLambda25A29444",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
        "SourceArn": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "arn:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
              },
              ":execute-api:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              },
              ":",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
              },
              ":",
              {
                "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
              },
              "/test-invoke-stage/*/*"
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "GatewayproxyANYCE067C19": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
      "Properties": {
        "HttpMethod": "ANY",
        "ResourceId": {
          "Ref": "Gatewayproxy441946D2"
        },
        "RestApiId": {
          "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
        },
        "AuthorizationType": "NONE",
        "Integration": {
          "IntegrationHttpMethod": "POST",
          "Type": "AWS_PROXY",
          "Uri": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "arn:",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                },
                ":apigateway:",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/",
                {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ReadLambda25A29444",
                    "Arn"
                  ]
                },
                "/invocations"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "GatewayANYApiPermissionMyTestStackGatewayDAACF61FANY796B270C": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ReadLambda25A29444",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
        "SourceArn": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "arn:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
              },
              ":execute-api:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              },
              ":",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
              },
              ":",
              {
                "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
              },
              "/",
              {
                "Ref": "GatewayDeploymentStageprod62BC6904"
              },
              "/*/"
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "GatewayANYApiPermissionTestMyTestStackGatewayDAACF61FANY0A112ACD": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ReadLambda25A29444",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
        "SourceArn": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "arn:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
              },
              ":execute-api:",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              },
              ":",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
              },
              ":",
              {
                "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
              },
              "/test-invoke-stage/*/"
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "GatewayANY8DB43F89": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
      "Properties": {
        "HttpMethod": "ANY",
        "ResourceId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "Gateway43CB3636",
            "RootResourceId"
          ]
        },
        "RestApiId": {
          "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
        },
        "AuthorizationType": "NONE",
        "Integration": {
          "IntegrationHttpMethod": "POST",
          "Type": "AWS_PROXY",
          "Uri": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "arn:",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                },
                ":apigateway:",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/",
                {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ReadLambda25A29444",
                    "Arn"
                  ]
                },
                "/invocations"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ddbTable": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "Messages804FA4EB"
      }
    },
    "GatewayEndpoint4DF49EE0": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "https://",
            {
              "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
            },
            ".execute-api.",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            ".",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::URLSuffix"
            },
            "/",
            {
              "Ref": "GatewayDeploymentStageprod62BC6904"
            },
            "/"
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    "Url": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "https://",
            {
              "Ref": "Gateway43CB3636"
            },
            ".execute-api.",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            ".",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::URLSuffix"
            },
            "/",
            {
              "Ref": "GatewayDeploymentStageprod62BC6904"
            },
            "/"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Parameters": {
    "AssetParameters9f901872866f870648f5c33e2a134e29d428ef5dae05062b86e526b1012df22fS3Bucket503CC46A": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "S3 bucket for asset \"9f901872866f870648f5c33e2a134e29d428ef5dae05062b86e526b1012df22f\""
    },
    "AssetParameters9f901872866f870648f5c33e2a134e29d428ef5dae05062b86e526b1012df22fS3VersionKey6307BBBE": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "S3 key for asset version \"9f901872866f870648f5c33e2a134e29d428ef5dae05062b86e526b1012df22f\""
    },
    "AssetParameters9f901872866f870648f5c33e2a134e29d428ef5dae05062b86e526b1012df22fArtifactHashD58BF519": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Artifact hash for asset \"9f901872866f870648f5c33e2a134e29d428ef5dae05062b86e526b1012df22f\""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share more of the synth output to also include the rest api resource?

Comment: @LRutten Added full Synth in the question

Comment: Thanks! Is your goal to test if the api is invoking the right lambda or the right lambda HANDLER (so test the function name of the lambda itself)?

Comment: I plan to only have one handler in my lambda i.e. to read objects from dynamodb. Hence I need to test if my API Gateway is invoking only ReadLambda.